# igb intel driver won't compile and igb.ko copied from another image kernel says format is incorrect?

Tags: rhel, drivers, intel

Ok so I have a rhel 6 machine running a rt 3.2 kernel- basically it looks like it needs a driver update as it is a clone, the image sees the expansion card nic an intel i350 and uses those as two eth ports. It does not however want to use the motherboards i210 ethernet ports. igb is the driver for both of these devices so my plan was to simply load a new driver in over the old one and hope it fixes the issue. I have taken 2 approaches to this standard build it and modprobe on system and also try to build the .ko on another system and cp it over and replace the existing .ko file

```
rmmod igb //to remove the previous driver 
rpm -q igb // says there is no package igb so maybe it wasn't installed with rpm   

tar -zxf igb-5-7.2.tar.gz
cd igb-5.7.2/src
make install 
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.2.23-rt37.56.el6rt.x86_64'
  CC [M]  /lib/modules/3.2.23-rt37.56.el6rt.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/igb-5.7.2/src/igb_main.o
In file included from /lib/modules/3.2.23-rt37.56.el6rt.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/igb-5.7.2/src/igb.h:32,
                 from /lib/modules/3.2.23-rt37.56.el6rt.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/igb-5.7.2/src/igb_main.c:30:
/lib/modules/3.2.23-rt37.56.el6rt.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/igb-5.7.2/src/kcompat.h:4183: error: conflicting types for ‘netdev_features_t’
include/linux/netdev_features.h:15: note: previous declaration of ‘netdev_features_t’ was here
/lib/modules/3.2.23-rt37.56.el6rt.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/igb-5.7.2/src/kcompat.h:4212: error: redefinition of ‘ethtool_rxfh_indir_default’
include/linux/ethtool.h:769: note: previous definition of ‘ethtool_rxfh_indir_default’ was here
/lib/modules/3.2.23-rt37.56.el6rt.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/igb-5.7.2/src/igb_main.c:2441: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
/lib/modules/3.2.23-rt37.56.el6rt.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/igb-5.7.2/src/igb_main.c:2442: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
/lib/modules/3.2.23-rt37.56.el6rt.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/igb-5.7.2/src/igb_main.c:2488: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
/lib/modules/3.2.23-rt37.56.el6rt.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/igb-5.7.2/src/igb_main.c:2489: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
make[2]: *** [/lib/modules/3.2.23-rt37.56.el6rt.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/igb-5.7.2/src/igb_main.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/lib/modules/3.2.23-rt37.56.el6rt.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/igb-5.7.2/src] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.2.23-rt37.56.el6rt.x86_64'
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

if someone can maybe point out how to avoid the netdev_features_t and ethtool definition errors and just simply what I am doing wrong that would be great.

I also used the .ko file built on another system and copied over the exist .ko

```
modprobe igb //using .ko file from a newer system says headers are incompatible or incompatible format
```

so

A: am I doing something wrong with the build process ie didn't fully uninstall the old driver and its conflicting or another issue.

B: I used the latest driver should I use an older one since the kernel is so old

C: can you not use .ko files from other systems or do they have to be compiled against your specific kernel

thoughts and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The driver you are trying to compile is too radically different in age from the kernel you are trying to use it with.  You need to change to a kernel in the correct version range this driver was designed for.

Also, RHEL6 is obsolete, you should upgrade to a supported version, which might also help.

Comment: I agree with the updating idea but it is a rt image and has specific packages and hardware that are not available on newer kernels, ie I am stuck with the RHEL 6 for this instant. Is there a way to get older versions of the igb maybe from github perhaps? and more specifically is the 5.7.xx corresponding to the kernel version ? like I need an igb driver version of 3.2.xxxxxx like my kernel?

Comment: There's a couple of options...  You can hunt for the correct driver version for the kernel version you are using, but there is a possibility the older driver won't support your network cards.   The alternative is to backport the current driver to the older kernel, possibly by looking at what changes are made in the source between a driver that compiles and the new one.  It is also possible this has already been done and you just need to find it.  Good luck.

Comment: thanks for the info  I'll update the thread once I figure it out. also one last question as this is my first time dealing with device drivers, does the .ko file have to be compiled on your machine or does it just have to be compiled on a machine using the same or very near the same kernel? just for future reference

Comment: It has to be compiled with a compiler of the right architecture using the exact same kernel version using the same kernel options.  Most distros save an options file along with the kernel in /boot although I've not tried cross compiling a kernel module recently so the details of how to use those has faded.  Compiler version might matter.